# editing an Entity using jpa

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to edit and entity using JPA, I used this but it doesn't do anything, why?

```
public void editExam(Exam e) {
        Exam ex=getExam(e.getIdExam());
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("QuizPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        ex.setQuestions(e.getQuestions());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
```

I am trying to change the value of `questions` which a List.
this is how it is coded in my `Exam` Entity Class

```
    @OneToMany (cascade = ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="jnt_Exam_Question",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idExam"), 
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idQuestion"))
    private List<Question> questions;
```

my getExam() method

```
public Exam getExam(Long idExam) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("QuizPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        String req1 ="select e from Exam e where e.idExam = ?1";
        Query q1 = em.createQuery(req1);
        q1.setParameter(1, idExam);
        Exam e =(Exam) q1.getSingleResult();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return e;
    }
```

Comment: and what state is "ex" in at that point? It is `detached` since its EntityManager is closed! You need to `merge` it using the new EntityManager. But then this is in any JPA tutorial. And why are you creating an EntityManagerFactory multiple times?!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by creating only one instance of `EntityManagerFactory`